# Adding WidgetKit extension to existing iOS project with Objective -C and swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, widgetkit

I am trying to use widgetKit extension to my existing Xcode project. I get following error when I run the App.

### Unable to install "AppName"
Domain: com.apple.dt.MobileDeviceErrorDomain
Code: -402653007
User Info: {
DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-06-22 11:57:05 +0000";
IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstalliPhoneLauncher;
}

*This app contains an app extension that specifies an extension point identifier that is not supported on this version of iOS for the value of the NSExtensionPointIdentifier key in its Info.plist.*

1. Xcode version - 14.2
2. App deployment version - iOS 14
3. WidgetKitExtension deployment version - iOS 16.2
4. Device used to test iPhone 13 - iOS 16.5*

Thanks
Ranjit

Answer (score 0):

The value for `NSExtensionPointIdentifier` in the extension's Info.plist must be `com.apple.widgetkit-extension`. Having a different value could result in this error.

Comment: When answering a question, please try not to ask another question instead of an answer. If you do intend to ask the poster a question at least include an answer. If you have questions add them as comments under the original question and not as a new answer.

Comment: @MartinsOnuoha Thanks for the feedback, I do not have enough reputation to add a comment but I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your error info provide limited info.
Have you enabled the `Capability` of `App Groups`, The weight target should be in one group with your main project